# Open a web from Winforms with session initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, session

I have a Winforms application which use a login to authenticate. I also have a ASP.net web which uses the same login parameters and then save the user in session.

I want to open the web from the Winforms with the user session initialized, so the user doesn't needs to log again.

Is this possible?

With System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://myweb.com?login=XXX&pass=YYY") I can get the values and simulate the login event, but I don't want to pass user parameters in the URL. Any Suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do this would be to create a token table where you generate a login token against a userid.

When opening your site open a different page ie. LoginToken.aspx and retrieve the userID from the table and save it in session. Then redirect the user to your default page.

I would not advise passing user credentials via the query string.

Comment: Thanks, I like your idea.